# For some reason, pycharm is not able to compute my following code for finding factors of a number

Tags: python, list, numbers

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number : "))
a = [1, n]
fac = 2
    while fac <= n/2:
        if n % fac == 0:
            a.append(fac)
            fac += 1

print(a)
```

A simple code to print the factors of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code like this

```
if n % fac == 0:
    a.append(fac)
fac += 1
```